# undefined symbol: amqp_ssl_socket_set_verify_peer in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, php-amqp

Just updated PHP to 5.6.30 and every PHP request produces a WARNING

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/amqp.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/amqp.so: undefined symbol: amqp_ssl_socket_set_verify_peer in Unknown on line 0
```

Package `php-pecl-amqp-1.8.0-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64` is installed and the latest version.

I use CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

Comment: For such question directly related to my repostiory, probably better to use  https://forum.remirepo.net/ or https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only reproduce with librabbitmq-last version 0.7.1

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi-php56 install php-pecl-amqp
...
Installed:
  php-pecl-amqp.x86_64 0:1.8.0-1.el6.remi.5.6                                                                                                                                       

Dependency Installed:
  librabbitmq-last.x86_64 0:0.8.0-1.el6.remi                                                                                                                                        

# php -v 
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2017 08:09:42) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

# php -m | grep amqp
amqp
```

So ensure you have latest **librabbitmq-last version 0.8.0** (in "remi-safe" repository, which is required and enabled by default)

P.S. indeed, this symbol was not in 0.7.x, but was introduced in [0.8.0](http://rpms.remirepo.net/compat_reports/librabbitmq/0.7.1_to_0.8.0/compat_report.html#Binary_Added)

Comment: To avoid such mistake, php-pecl-amqp-1.8.0-2 now have a dependency on librabbitmq-last >= 0.8.0.

Comment: Updated system via yum update, and everything went fine.